# search from columns of one dataframe in another another dataframe

Tags: r

I need to search the Item LC of dataframe final1 which are not there in Item ToLC of dataframe lctolc.

How to do that.

I tried using merge but it is creating some extra rows in new dataframe.

final1:

```
   Item  LC     SS Freq
1   A   MW92    20  0
2   A   RM02    10  0
3   A   RM03    5   1
4   A   LO99    99  0
5   B   WK14    112 0
6   B   RS11    30  1

Item <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
LC <- c("MW92", "RM02", "RM03" ,"LO99", "WK14", "RS11")
SS <- c(20, 10, 5, 99, 112, 30)
Freq <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
final1 <- data.frame(Item, LC, SS, Freq, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

lctolc:

```
   Item  LC     ToLC
1   A   MW92    OY01
2   A   OY01    RM11
3   A   RM11    RM02
4   B   WK14    RS11
5   B   RS11    ZM78

Item <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
LC <- c("MW92", "OY01", "RM11", "WK14", "RS11")
ToLC <- c("OY01", "RM11", "RM02", "RS11", "ZM78")
lctolcl <- data.frame(Item, LC, ToLC, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Output:

```
   Item  LC     SS Freq
1   A   MW92    20  0
2   A   RM03    5   1
3   A   LO99    99  0
4   B   WK14    112 0
```

Can someone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be performed using `match` or its equivalent `%in%`.

```
> final1[!(final1$LC %in% lctolcl$ToLC), ]
  Item   LC  SS Freq
1    A MW92  20    0
3    A RM03   5    1
4    A LO99  99    0
5    B WK14 112    0
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `anti_join` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(final1, lctolcl, by = c("Item", "LC" = "ToLC"))
#  Item   LC  SS Freq
#1    A MW92  20    0
#2    A RM03   5    1
#3    A LO99  99    0
#4    B WK14 112    0
```